# Пример авторизации ВК Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, вконтакте, auth

Хочу сделать авторизацию/регистрацию через ВКонтакте, нашел [официальную библиотеку](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-clients-vkontakte.html). Хотелось бы посмотреть пример такой авторизации, или как вариант пример с авторизацией через [ulogin](https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-ulogin), со всеми вьюхами, контроллером, моделью. Так же. Где это можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большую часть работы потребуется выполнить на фронтенде.

Библиотека ulogin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
```

Блок авторизации через соц. сети на странице.

```
<div class="social_block">
    <!-- fields - это список полей которые вам нужны(имя, фамилия, email, телефон). Они будут отоброжатся средствами ulogin при регистрации. -->
    <!-- callback - это js функция которая будет вызвана после нажатия кнопки "продожить" в форме ulogin. В нашем случаи будет вызыватся  get_ulogin-->
    <!-- redirect_uri - оставляем пустым -->
    <div id="uLogin1" x-ulogin-params="display=buttons;fields=first_name,last_name,email,phone;providers=vkontakte,odnoklassniki,mailru,facebook;callback=get_ulogin;redirect_uri=">
        <span data-uloginbutton="facebook"></span>
        <span data-uloginbutton="vkontakte"></span>
        <span data-uloginbutton="odnoklassniki"></span>
        <span data-uloginbutton="mailru"></span>
        <span data-uloginbutton="yandex"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Скрытая форма для данных

```
<form name="ulogin_form" method="POST" action="user/ulogin" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="ulogin_email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="ulogin_phone">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="ulogin_name">
    <input type="text" name="sename" id="ulogin_sename">
    <input type="text" name="password" id="ulogin_password">
</form>
```

callback функция

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Эта функция будет вызыватся после нажатия кнопки "продолжить". В функцию будет передан токен*/
    function get_ulogin(token)
    {
        //отправлям ajax запрос для получения данных о пользователе
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ulogin.ru/token.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'jsonp',
            async: false,
            //Передаем токен и свой адрес сайта. Адрес сайта по моему можно даже оставить пустым
            data: {'token': token, 'host': '<?= Yii::$app->request->getServerName() ?>'},
            success: function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                //Получеными данными о пользователе, заполняем скрытую форму
                var user_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#ulogin_email").val(user_data.email);
                $("#ulogin_phone").val(user_data.phone);
                $("#ulogin_name").val(user_data.first_name);
                $("#ulogin_sename").val(user_data.last_name);
                $("#ulogin_password").val(user_data.uid);
                //Отправляем форму с данными к себе на сервер
                document.ulogin_form.submit();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

На бэкенде нужно будет выполнить валидацию днных из формы и выполнить проверку существованиея пользователя. Если пользователь с таким email не существует то выполняем регистрацию. Если пользователь с таким email существует и пароль подходит то выполняем авторизацию. Если пользователь с таким email существует и пароль не подходит то показываем сообщение об ошибке.

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Ulogin;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /* Акшен для регистрация через ulogin */
    public function actionUlogin()
    {
        $user = new Ulogin();
        if ( $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'') && $user->validate() ) {
            if ($user->uLogin()) {
                return $this->redirect('/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Модель

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class Ulogin extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $sename;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $phone;

    public function uLogin()
    {
        $user = User::findByEmail($this->email);

         //Если пользователь с такой эл. почтой сущесвует то выполняем авторизацию
         if ($user) {
            //Здесь будет авторизация
         } else {
            //Здесь будет регистрация
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: email контакт не отдаёт

Answer (score 3):

Довольно неплохой пример использования, от самих же разработчиков, можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/quick-start.md).

Добавление действия в контроллере:

```
use app\components\AuthHandler;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onAuthSuccess($client)
    {
        (new AuthHandler($client))->handle();
    }
}
```

Где реализация **AuthHandler** должна быть приблизительно следующая :

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use app\models\Auth;
use app\models\User;
use Yii;
use yii\authclient\ClientInterface;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * AuthHandler handles successful authentication via Yii auth component
 */
class AuthHandler
{
    /**
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    private $client;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $attributes = $this->client->getUserAttributes();
        $email = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'email');
        $id = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'id');
        $nickname = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'login');

        /* @var Auth $auth */
        $auth = Auth::find()->where([
            'source' => $this->client->getId(),
            'source_id' => $id,
        ])->one();

        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            if ($auth) { // login
                /* @var User $user */
                $user = $auth->user;
                $this->updateUserInfo($user);
                Yii::$app->user->login($user, Yii::$app->params['user.rememberMeDuration']);
            } else { // signup
                if ($email !== null && User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->exists()) {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', [
                        Yii::t('app', "User with the same email as in {client} account already exists but isn't linked to it. Login using email first to link it.", ['client' => $this->client->getTitle()]),
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $password = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(6);
                    $user = new User([
                        'username' => $nickname,
                        'github' => $nickname,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'password' => $password,
                    ]);
                    $user->generateAuthKey();
                    $user->generatePasswordResetToken();

                    $transaction = User::getDb()->beginTransaction();

                    if ($user->save()) {
                        $auth = new Auth([
                            'user_id' => $user->id,
                            'source' => $this->client->getId(),
                            'source_id' => (string)$id,
                        ]);
                        if ($auth->save()) {
                            $transaction->commit();
                            Yii::$app->user->login($user, Yii::$app->params['user.rememberMeDuration']);
                        } else {
                            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', [
                                Yii::t('app', 'Unable to save {client} account: {errors}', [
                                    'client' => $this->client->getTitle(),
                                    'errors' => json_encode($auth->getErrors()),
                                ]),
                            ]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', [
                            Yii::t('app', 'Unable to save user: {errors}', [
                                'client' => $this->client->getTitle(),
                                'errors' => json_encode($user->getErrors()),
                            ]),
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // user already logged in
            if (!$auth) { // add auth provider
                $auth = new Auth([
                    'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                    'source' => $this->client->getId(),
                    'source_id' => (string)$attributes['id'],
                ]);
                if ($auth->save()) {
                    /** @var User $user */
                    $user = $auth->user;
                    $this->updateUserInfo($user);
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', [
                        Yii::t('app', 'Linked {client} account.', [
                            'client' => $this->client->getTitle()
                        ]),
                    ]);
                } else {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', [
                        Yii::t('app', 'Unable to link {client} account: {errors}', [
                            'client' => $this->client->getTitle(),
                            'errors' => json_encode($auth->getErrors()),
                        ]),
                    ]);
                }
            } else { // there's existing auth
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', [
                    Yii::t('app',
                        'Unable to link {client} account. There is another user using it.',
                        ['client' => $this->client->getTitle()]),
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    private function updateUserInfo(User $user)
    {
        $attributes = $this->client->getUserAttributes();
        $github = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'login');
        if ($user->github === null && $github) {
            $user->github = $github;
            $user->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Для вью можно использовать уже готовый компонент виджет :

```
<?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
     'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'],
     'popupMode' => false,
]) ?>
```

Comment: @withoutname , а как должна выглядеть модель? И в данном случае как я понял пример для github.

Comment: @XenK модель чего?

Comment: @withoutname User

Comment: @XenK думаю в модель будет достаточно добавить поля, которые помогут вам связать юзера с его ВК страницей, на пример, `vkProfileId`, добавить также модель `VkProfile`, которая будет содержать информацию со страницы пользователя VK. Если проще - модель должна содержать некоторый объем данных, который вы рассчитываете получить с нее, и спрашивать "как должна выглядеть" - не имеет смысла, т.к. представления о подобных моделях может быть разное.

Comment: email контакт не отдаёт